# Python - How to pass iterables into product()?

Tags: python, product

I was trying to use the product() function in Python. I know product() takes a bunch of iterables and does the Cartesian product of all of them.

Now I put all the iterables in a list. I'm wondering how to pass all the iterables in that list at once? I can't pass in the list to product directly because then product()'ll treat it as one iterable. 
For example, I have a list of lists:

```
[[1,2,3],['a','b']]
```

How can I pass [1,2,3] and ['a','b'] to product, so it becomes equivalent to product([1,2,3],['a','b'])?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 l = [[1, 2, 3], ('a', 'b')]
 product(*l)
```

This is called [Unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Answer (score 5):

Use [argument expansion](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (unpacking):

```
vals = [[1,2,3],['a','b']]
product(*vals)
```

It works similar to this:

```
>>> x, y = [[1,2,3],['a','b']]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
>>> y
['a', 'b']
```